# Getting data from from database using Angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs, database

I'm new to angularjsand I just used the method $http.get(...) to get data from a database for use in my application.

But I wonder how safe this method is??

Anyone could easily see my database since it stored in json format in the link under the get method

Is there any other method to retrieve and use data from a database and use it in an angular application??

Comment: The best way is create a restful API backend (for example in PHP). Then your app (Angular) will call /backend/users/get and the PHP will connect to DB and return JSON data. You can easily secure your app in the backend (Angular will post security token, which will be need for data returning). So if anybody will see your source code, he will see only the backend URLs, not the data. And if he will call the URL directly (without auth token), noting will happen.

Comment: i think you can check this link out https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/security